# How to put a logo in NavigationView in SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swiftui

I am trying to use a logo image instead of a NavigationView title at the top section of the app. Couldn't find any documentation of using images inside a NavigationView.

Comment: It is not clear what you need. Add some images to clarify what the result do you expect

Comment: "I am trying to use a logo image instead of a NavigationView title at the top section of the app." That's a very clear explanation of what's needed.

Answer (score 36):

### iOS 14+

Starting from iOS 14 you can create a `ToolbarItem` with the `principal` placement:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Text("Test")
                .toolbar {
                    ToolbarItem(placement: .principal) {
                        Image(systemName: "ellipsis.circle")
                    }
                }
        }
    }
}
```

See the [`ToolbarItemPlacement` documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/toolbaritemplacement) for more *placements*.

Comment: this is by far the best answer if you can use iOS 14+

Answer (score 17):

`NavigationView.navigationBarTitle()` can *only* take a `Text()` argument right now. You could instead use `.navigationBarItems()` to set an `Image` as either the `trailing` or `leading` argument, but this is the SwiftUI equivalent of `UINavigationItem.leftBarButtonItem[s]` and `UINavigationItem.rightBarButtonItem[s]`, which means that you're restricted to navigation bar button dimensions. But if you're ok with that, you may want to set a *blank* title so that you can specify a standard-height navigation bar.

## Hard-Coded Positioning

If you can stand to live with yourself, you *can* fake a centered nav bar item by hard-coding padding around the image, like

```
.padding(.trailing, 125),
```

[image]

(Note that I deliberately positioned it off-center so that you can see that it's hard-coded.)

## Slightly Less Hard-Coded Positioning

Even better would be to wrap the whole thing in a `GeometryReader { geometry in ... }` block to use the screen dimensions to calculate precise positioning, if you know the exact width of the image you're using:

```
GeometryReader { geometry in
    NavigationView {
        ...
    }
        .navigationBarTitle(Text(""), displayMode: .inline)
        .navigationBarItems(trailing:
            PresentationButton(
                Image(systemName: "person.crop.circle")
                    .imageScale(.large)
                    .padding(.trailing, (geometry.size.width / 2.0) + -30), // image width = 60
                destination: ProfileHost()
            )
        )
```

[image]

If you don't want to hack it, here's what you can do:

## Standard nav bar height, left button item

```
.navigationBarTitle(Text(""), displayMode: .inline)
.navigationBarItems(leading:
    PresentationButton(
        Image(systemName: "person.crop.circle")
            .imageScale(.large)
            .padding(),
        destination: ProfileHost()
    )
)
```

[image]

## Standard nav bar height, right button item

```
.navigationBarTitle(Text(""), displayMode: .inline)
.navigationBarItems(trailing:
    PresentationButton(
        Image(systemName: "person.crop.circle")
            .imageScale(.large)
            .padding(),
        destination: ProfileHost()
    )
)
```

[image]

## Expanded nav bar height, no title, left button item

```
.navigationBarItems(leading:
    PresentationButton(
        Image(systemName: "person.crop.circle")
            .imageScale(.large)
            .padding(),
        destination: ProfileHost()
    )
)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I also did the same thing which only allowed to put image either at the leading or trailing edges. Maybe in later release, they will include the capability to have more items inside navigationView

Comment: Hello @NRitH , I tried your solution but there is an issue. When I use  ".padding(.trailing, 125)" to horizontally align the logo center it is not working perfect in all screen sizes. For example in I pad it is not even close to center. Do you have a solution for that? How can I align it in center for every possible screen sizes.

Comment: There's no issue at all. My solution wasn't _designed_ to work at all screen sizes. It's up to _you_ to calculate the value of the padding for the screen size.

Comment: I'm assuming PresentationButton is not a system object. Also, it only seems to work for me when I put .navigationBarTitle and .navigationBarItems inside the scope of NavigationView after one of the existing objects.

Answer (score 10):

Use this:

```
NavigationView {
    Text("Hello, SwiftUI!")
        .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
        .toolbar {
            ToolbarItem(placement: .principal) {
                HStack {
                    Image(systemName: "sun.min.fill")
                    Text("Title").font(.headline)
                }
            }
        }
}
```

Credit: https://sarunw.com/posts/custom-navigation-bar-title-view-in-swiftui/

Answer (score 6):

With [SwiftUIX](https://github.com/SwiftUIX/SwiftUIX), you can use `navigationBarTitleView(View)`:

```
NavigationView() {
    NavigationLink(destination:YourView().navigationBarTitleView(Image(systemName: "message.fill")))
}
```

[image]

Comment: The rabbit hold leads to `UIViewControllerRepresentable` :(. SwiftUIX is a nice find tho, good place to borrow ideas and contribute.

Comment: I've added SwiftUIX, but am unable to see any functions called navigationBarTitleView

Comment: @andrei check out their docs and see if things have changed, swiftuix on github.

Comment: @Zorayr already did but no references to it, they must have removed it because of support added in ios 14, but I'm trying to work this out on ios 13 as well

Comment: @andrei hey! Developer of SwiftUIX here, the `navigationBarTitleView(_:)` is still very much in place. Could you report an issue with a repro if you aren't able to use it?

Comment: @VatsalManot it was just me being stupid and not importing the library in my current file. navigationBarTitleView(_:) is available and works great

Comment: @andrei hahaha no worries, happens to the best of us.

Answer (score 5):

I don't want to claim 100% accuracy whether title image positioned at center but visually it looks center to me. Do your judgment and adjust padding :)

[image]

Here is code:

```
            .navigationBarTitle(
            Text("")
            , displayMode: .inline)
            .navigationBarItems(leading:
                HStack {
                    Button(action: {
                    }) {
                        Image(systemName: "arrow.left")
                    }.foregroundColor(Color.oceanWhite)
                    Image("oceanview-logo")
                        .resizable()
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                        .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                        .frame(width: 60, height: 40, alignment: .center)
                    .padding(UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width/4+30)
                }
                ,trailing:

                HStack {

                    Button(action: {
                    }) {
                        Image(systemName: "magnifyingglass")
                        }.foregroundColor(Color.oceanWhite)
                }
        )
```

Answer (score 3):

To extend on NRitH's answer, putting your logo in a different component (to borrow a React way of putting it) may help anyone looking to understand the concepts.

The actual Image can be wrapped in *any* container view such as a VStack, etc. An example of setting up a struct as a component to be used in our navigation items could be something like the following:

```
struct NavLogo: View {

    var body: some View {
            VStack {
                Image("app-logo")
                    .resizable()
                    .aspectRatio(2, contentMode: .fit)
                    .imageScale(.large)
            }
            .frame(width: 200)
            .background(Color.clear)
    }
}
```

When the aspect ratio is set, only the width needs to be set on the frame on the container view. We could also set a property in the **NavLogo** to set width and/or height from property dependency injection. Regardless, our navigationBarItems becomes very straight forward and more readable

```
NavigationView {
    Text("Home View")
        .navigationBarItems(
            leading: NavLogo()
            trailing: ProfileButton()
        )
    }
```

Comment: this worked pretty good, but instead of hardcoding 200, this cantered it exact: `.frame(width: .infinity)`

Comment: actually had to use geometry.size.width. See @NRitH's answer

Answer (score 0):

On iOS 13, a little hacky way to achieve this:

```
private var logo: some View {
    Image("logo-image")
}

var body: some View {
    GeometryReader { g in
        content()
            .navigationBarTitle("")
            .navigationBarItems(leading:
                                    ZStack(alignment: .leading) {
                                        logo.frame(width: g.size.width).padding(.trailing, 8)
                                        HStack {
                                            leadingItems().padding(.leading, 10)
                                            Spacer()
                                            trailingItems().padding(.trailing, 10)
                                        }
                                        .frame(width: g.size.width)
                                    }
                                )
    }
}
```

Answer (score -3):

Try the following.

```
struct ContainerView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Image(systemName: "person.crop.square")
            ContentView()
        }
    }
}
```

It worked for me.

Make sure you change ContentView to ContainerView inside SceneDelegate.swift before running on simulator or device.